# Horizontal ListView which, instead of scrolling, returns the remaining items on another line

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll, line

Please, How to create a horizontal ListView which, instead of scrolling, returns the remaining items on another line.

i don't want to scroll

[image]

but i want to do this :
[image]

I don't know how to do this. Thank for help

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Wrap` widget

Example :

```
Wrap( direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: _items.map((i) => Text('Item $i')).toList(),
)
```

or

```
Wrap(
direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```